# Are there any natural languages with exclusively asyndetic coordination?

Tags: syntax, morphology, coordination

Are there any languages with exclusively asyndetic coordination, i.e. in which constituents are coordinated solely by juxtaposition, with disjunctive (or) or adversative (but) meaninigs communicated by adverbs or other word classes that don't qualify as coordinators?

Comment: I believe many Amazonian languages have borrowed their word for "and" from Spanish or Portuguese, and thus may have had no coordinators before that, but I don't have a pointer for this claim.

Comment: Aymara was such a language before the contact with Spanish. The pragmatic meeting of adjacency of clauses was mainly implicit (inferred from context).